# How do I sum a table of data by the month?

Tags: google-sheets

Please help. I'm trying to sum up my expenses in specific categories by month for the whole year. I keep trying different formulas and they aren't working.

Expenses are recorded on sheet 2. Trying to sum on Shet 1.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zUgZUkNjsCqdgyiiaL1REsI7y2O3mUV4Czv1SOzzLlI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Reformat your data in Cr/Dr: Let E:E be transaction type and F:F be amount. Then you can use `QUERY`. Data Entry should be long rather than wide.

Comment: Your question would be better if you had some sample data in your actual post. Once that link stops working, this question has no value. One of the tenets of Stack Exchange is that questions and their answers be useful to more than just the person asking.

Answer (score 1):

This was the "original" expense sheet, I just added the month column in blue:
[image]

On the other sheet, where calculations were needed, I suggested very simple formulas with SUMIF:

[image]

=sumif('2018 Cr/Dr'!$D:$D,C2,'2018 Cr/Dr'!$F:$F)

'2018 Cr/Dr' is the "original" expense sheet

$D:$D the column for the month in blue

C2 the month we are looking for

$F:$F the column for "dining out"

Hope now is more helpful!

Answer (score -2):

Check what I did with your file
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10jAz3Pu2elVRsjdCaKymyG3FVZIunDNAyAta8cjajrs/edit#gid=948959922

Does this help?

Comment: We like answers to be self-contained. When that link stops working this "answer" will become useless. Links should supplement answers; please [edit] to include your solution.